# google signin using javascript throws an error in android web view

Tags: android, google-signin

I have integrated a javascript google login button on a php based web page. The button works okay when the web page is accessed from the url.

But it throws the following error message in android web view:

Error 403: disallowed_useragent

And on the ios web view the google login would not launch.

I am looking for a solution to make the google login work on android and ios web view.

Comment: You can't use a web view it needs to open the auth screen on the system browser